# How to check if you can connect to an apache server using IP Address in android?

Tags: android, apache, connection

I have an activity that would connect to an Apache server in a a remote computer using IP Address and ports. I can connect to the server manually and the WAMP home page shows on the devices browser.

What I want to do is to check if you can actually connect to the server using the IP Address entered into an EditText in an activity.

So after it clicks a button, it would check the connection and if successful to goes to the next activity. And if it cannot use the ip address or if the ip address does not have Apache, it would show a Toast.

Comment: So what do you want to check? If an apache instance is alive or if an ip address is linked to a specific apache instance.

Comment: oh.. what should I check? But basically I want to check if you can connect to an Apache server using the IP Address

Comment: And maybe if the connection is open and I can access php files

Answer (score 2):

Check the http response.
If it is 200 so you know that everything is fine.

Example :

```
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(serverUrl));
    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        // Everything is OK
    } else {
        // Something wrong
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Comment: it returns false and does not connect to an already running apache server